# Split a Max/Min score into 3 bands with fixed threshold values in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

Given the max/min scores 90-22, 100-55, 85-41, 93-30, 40-18 I need to split those into 3 bands each with the thresholds at 80 and 60. So for the first pair that would give me (90-80, 80-60, 60-22), the last pair would give (null-80, null-60, 40-18).

I've got this partially working with the SQL below, the problem I'm having is with edge cases, for example for the final pair (40-18) the UpperRed value is being returned as 60. And I know I have problems if the max/min scores don't go below 80 (so 93-85 for example, because that will also return me an amber range which I don't want).

```
DECLARE @GreenLower INT
DECLARE @AmberUpper INT
DECLARE @AmberLower INT
DECLARE @RedUpper INT

SET @GreenLower = 80
SET @AmberUpper = 80
SET @AmberLower = 60
SET @RedUpper = 60

DECLARE @Scores TABLE
  (
   GroupedBy VARCHAR(50) ,
   PCTMax INT ,
   PCTAvg INT ,
   PCTMin INT ,
   ALLAvg INT ,
   AllMax INT ,
   AllMin INT
  )

INSERT  INTO @Scores
VALUES  ( 'Prov1', 80, 75, 63, 50, 90, 22 )
INSERT  INTO @Scores
VALUES  ( 'Prov2', 100, 96, 70, 80, 100, 55 )
INSERT  INTO @Scores
VALUES  ( 'Prov3', 72, 58, 44, 62, 85, 41 )
INSERT  INTO @Scores
VALUES  ( 'Prov4', 90, 78, 58, 59, 93, 30 )
INSERT  INTO @Scores
VALUES  ( 'Prov5', 63, 25, 21, 30, 40, 18 )

SELECT  GroupedBy ,
            PCTMax ,
    PCTAvg ,
    PCTMin ,
    AllAvg ,
    CASE WHEN AllMax > 79 THEN AllMax ELSE NULL END AS GreenUpper ,
    CASE WHEN AllMin > 79 THEN AllMin ELSE @GreenLower END AS GreenLower ,

    CASE WHEN AllMax < 79 THEN AllMax ELSE 
        CASE WHEN AllMax > 79 THEN @AmberUpper ELSE  NULL END 
    END AS AmberUpper ,
    @AmberLower AS AmberLower ,

    CASE WHEN AllMin > 59 THEN NULL ELSE @RedUpper END AS RedUpper ,
    CASE WHEN AllMin > 59 THEN NULL ELSE AllMin END AS RedLower

FROM    @Scores
```

Ultimately this data will be more dynamic and pull real values, but for now I'm just trying to get the output logic correct so I can plug it into the graph component and produce a graph that looks like this:
[image: Whiskers chart]

Comment: THANK YOU for providing sample data!

Comment: What is the point of showing an `Upper` value as NULL and the corresponding `Lower` one as an actual value for that band when the given range doesn't match the band? I'm asking that because I'm trying to figure out what should be displayed as `RedLower` for `93-85`. Should it be `0`? (What I would probably do is display `NULL` for both `Upper` and `Lower` if the range doesn't intersect the band.)

Comment: There's no real point to showing null and a value when the range doesn't match a band only that it was easier to do and, when the data is plugged into MS Chart, produces the right result on the graph. A RangeColumn chart needs both max and min, if it gets a null for either it doesn't show the range, so if the result is null-80 there would be no green band. If you can get NULL for both upper and lower that's great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does the job in two steps:

1. Split every range into rows of Upper & Lower values, one row per subrange.
2. Unpivot the subranges to show every group of them on the same row.

```
SELECT
  GroupedBy,
  PCTMax,
  PCTAvg,
  PCTMin,
  AllAvg,
  GreenUpper = MAX(CASE BandName WHEN 'Green' THEN Upper END),
  GreenLower = MAX(CASE BandName WHEN 'Green' THEN Lower END),
  AmberUpper = MAX(CASE BandName WHEN 'Amber' THEN Upper END),
  AmberLower = MAX(CASE BandName WHEN 'Amber' THEN Lower END),
  RedUpper   = MAX(CASE BandName WHEN 'Red'   THEN Upper END),
  RedLower   = MAX(CASE BandName WHEN 'Red'   THEN Lower END)
FROM (
  SELECT
    s.GroupedBy,
    s.PCTMax,
    s.PCTAvg,
    s.PCTMin,
    s.AllAvg,
    b.BandName,
    Upper = CASE
      WHEN s.AllMax >= b.BandMin AND s.AllMin <= b.BandMax THEN
        CASE
          WHEN b.BandMax > s.AllMax THEN s.AllMax
          ELSE b.BandMax
        END
    END,
    Lower = CASE
      WHEN s.AllMax >= b.BandMin AND s.AllMin <= b.BandMax THEN
        CASE
          WHEN b.BandMin < s.AllMin THEN s.AllMin
          ELSE b.BandMin
        END
    END
  FROM Scores s
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'Green', 80, 2147483647 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Amber', 60, 79         UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Red'  ,  0, 59
  ) b (BandName, BandMin, BandMax)
) s
GROUP BY
  GroupedBy,
  PCTMax,
  PCTAvg,
  PCTMin,
  AllAvg
```

The subselect implements the first step and uses an auxiliary inline table to split ranges. The outer select uses grouping to unpivot the obtained value pairs.

You can play with this solution [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72dd7/1), where I added more edge cases to the `Scores` table for better illustration of splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  GroupedBy
      , AllMax
      , AllMin
      , CASE WHEN AllMax > 79 THEN AllMax
             ELSE NULL
        END AS GreenUpper
      , CASE WHEN AllMin > 79 THEN AllMin
             ELSE @GreenLower
        END AS GreenLower
      , CASE WHEN AllMax BETWEEN 61 AND 80 THEN AllMax
             WHEN AllMax > 79
                  AND AllMin < 80 THEN @AmberUpper
             ELSE NULL
        END AS AmberUpper
      , @AmberLower AS AmberLower
      , @RedUpper AS RedUpper
      , CASE WHEN AllMin > 59 THEN NULL
             ELSE AllMin
        END AS RedLower
FROM    @Scores
```

Comment: Almost there but when I run that the RedUpper for Prov5 is 60 but it should be 40

Comment: If I change the values for Prov4 to 76 and 65 then I get a range of 76-60 (so it doesn't handle the lower end of the range), though when I set 93-82 that is handled ok